# Eq. $x^2+y^2=r^2$ in complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, coordinate-systems, complex-geometry

Imagine we draw Cartesian and complex x-y plane side by side. Only difference now between them is there is a 'i' with y in complex . In Cartesian equation of circle is $x^2+y^2=r^2$ so in complex plane should not this circle be (replace y by iy )
$$x^2+(iy)^2=r^2\implies x^2-y^2=r^2$$

I have studied complex for long but I am still having this doubt I think I am mixing two different concepts .

> If we consider Cartesian and complex plane as ordered pair then how and how much putting a 'i ' makes it  different ?
> Is complex just another coordinate system ?

Comment: We don't replace just $y$ with $iy$. We replace $(x,y)$ with $x+iy$.

Comment: In the complex plane it's more natural to write it as $\,|z|^2=r^2\,$. You can derive that form using that $\,x=\frac{1}{2}\left(z+\bar z\right), y=\frac{1}{2i}\left(z-\bar z\right)\,$ and $\,z \bar z=|z|^2\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A circle with radius $r$ in the $\mathbb R^2$ is $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x^2+y^2=r^2\}$.

This is no different in the complex world; that is, a circle with radius $r$ in $\mathbb C$ is $\{x+iy\in\mathbb C:x^2+y^2=r^2\}$.

Comment: Are all curves $f(x,y)=0$ same in both complex and x-y plane and difference only comes when we consider curve in terms of $z=x+iy$ ?

Comment: Yes, a curve in $\mathbb R^2$ is $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:f(x,y)=0\}$ and that same curve in $\mathbb C$ is $\{x+iy\in\mathbb R^2:f(x,y)=0\}$. This should not be confused with a function $f(z)$, where $z\in\mathbb C$. For example, the function $f(z)=z^2$ is not $\{x+iy\in\mathbb R^2:y=x^2\}$.